# select inside case statement in where clause tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a case condition inside where clause which is working fine without any sub queries, but it is not working with sub queries

for example

```
declare @isadmin varchar(5) = 'M'

select * from Aging_calc_all a where a.AccountNumber in 
(case @isadmin when 'M' then 1 else 0 end)
```

which is working fine.

However this does not seem to work -

```
select * from Aging_calc_all a where a.AccountNumber in 
(case @isadmin when 'M' then (select AccountNumber from ACE_AccsLevelMaster where AssignedUser=7) else 0 end)
```

Any suggestions or this is a t-sql bug in 2008.

Comment: this may return multiple values `select AccountNumber from ACE_AccsLevelMaster where AssignedUser=7`, try `select COUNT(AccountNumber) from ACE_AccsLevelMaster where AssignedUser=7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're receiving is "Subquery returned more than 1 value", I believe. So you can't return multiple values after THEN.
You should rewrite your query to something like this:

```
select 
    * 
from Aging_calc_all a 
where 
    (@isadmin='M' and a.AccountNumber in (select AccountNumber from ACE_AccsLevelMaster where AssignedUser=7))
    or 
    (@isadmin<>'M' and a.AccountNumber=0)
```

Comment: one more thing: consider that no rows will be returned is @isadmin is null.

Comment: I thought about this but I tried to solve that with CASE :) I used this at now but can you please tell me why this is not possible with CASE? Thanks and 1 point.

Comment: @QMaster Because `CASE` works like this: "Evaluates a list of conditions and returns ONE of multiple possible result expressions.". It allows you to use comparison operators with `CASE`, but also means that `CASE` cannot return multiple values.

Comment: @AdamŁuniewski I tried to return different lists (with an special function that split an string list to chunks and returned as a table like records) as each CASE result but failed. I think as you said CASE can't do that as it's nature, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from Aging_calc_all a where a.AccountNumber in (
   SELECT AccountNumber 
     from ACE_AccsLevelMaster 
     where AssignedUser=7 AND @isadmin = 'M'
   UNION ALL select 0 where @isadmin <> 'M'
   )
```

**EDITED** To show how use multiple criteria

```
select * from Aging_calc_all a where a.AccountNumber in (
   SELECT AccountNumber 
     from ACE_AccsLevelMaster 
     where AssignedUser=7 AND @isadmin = 'M'
   -- case to select from another table:
   UNION ALL select * from ANOTHER_TABLE where @isadmin = 'A' 
   -- case to select from const set (1, 2, 3):
   UNION ALL select * from ( 
      select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3) x where @isadmin = 'B' 
   -- case to show how 'else' work
   UNION ALL select 0 where @isadmin not in( 'M', 'A', 'B')
   )
```

Comment: this seems to be working but this is not using case statements which can have multiple conditions.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya you can use as many `UNION ALL` criteria as CASE see my edit for details

Answer (score 1):

This should work(although it's not a direct answer of the question):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   aging_calc_all a 
WHERE  ( @isadmin <> 'M' AND a.accountnumber = 0 ) 
    OR ( @isadmin =  'M' AND a.accountnumber IN (SELECT accountnumber 
                                     FROM   ace_accslevelmaster 
                                     WHERE  assigneduser = 7) )
```